# Meaning and use of またと

Tags: grammar

> ここの夫婦ほど私たちとかけ離れた連中は**またと**いませんよ。
>   There's no one as different from us as the people here.

This is how I would translate the sentence without またと. Am I correct that this sentence works without またと?

I'm assuming that またと means "in addition/besides", but I'm struggling to understand how it fits into the sentence grammatically,  and what extra nuance it adds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual form is:

> 「[Object/Situation/Event] + は + **またと** + [Verb in **Negative** Form]」

The 「またと」 here functions to (emphatically) deny the likelihood of the [Object/Situation/Event] occurring again.

It is synonymous to 「二度{にど}と」、「ふたたび」、「めったに」, etc.

Therefore, the basic meaning of the sentence will pretty much stay the same even if you dropped the 「またと」, but it is often used to make it sound emphatic.

> I'm assuming that またと means "in addition/besides"

Not quite.  As I explained, it means (used in conjunction with a negative verb) something along the lines of "**(basically) never again**".

> 「ここの夫婦{ふうふ}ほど私{わたし}たちとかけ離{はな}れた連中{れんちゅう}はまたといませんよ。」

therefore means:

> "You shall never see/find a couple (or "people") as completely different from us as the married couple here."